# How to set jboss-classloading.xml on JBOSS EAP 6.4 for ear based build/project?

Tags: rest, class, jboss, loading, ear

I have Restful project with the structure below however if I set my jboss-classloading.xml  under myapp.ear META_INF folder as below , Does it how it supposed to be for ear and jar output after maven build ?

myapp.ear
 |
 |--- ejb1.jar

What exactly below means ?

```
<classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0"
          domain="IsolatedDomain"
          export-all="NON_EMPTY"
          import-all="true">
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

classloading.xml is a JBoss 5 feature and since JBoss AS 7 classloading is completely different. WARs and EARs are isolated by default. If you require more specific classloading control you can use the Dependencies line in a MANIFEST.MF (Maven can create this for you) or by using a jboss-deployment.xml file. 
hope this helps you. 
Oliver